# Create ServiceInstall in Wix on exe from unknown ahead path

Tags: wix, file-copying, serviceinstall

I have a problem that I'd appropriate your assistance with .
I'm using wix (with vs 2013) to create installer that does the following :
Copy all files from folder A to folder B (both user editable) .
If it contains some specific file create a windows service out of it .

I prefer to do it in Wix for easier support of upgrade \ uninstall etc ...

I have a problem with it :
I copy all the files using CopyFile element and For the service I need to specify the file name \ source in the File element for which I want to create a service , but I can't specify the Source since it's dynamic (even though I have a property for it).

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported by Windows Installer.  The underlying [ServiceInstall table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa371637(v=vs.85).aspx) doesn't allow you to specify the filename of the service:

> Component_
>
> External key to column one of the Component Table. Note
>   that to install this service using the InstallService table, the
>   KeyPath for this component must be the executable file for the
>   service.

The only way I see you could do what you are trying to do is if you use custom actions to emit temporary rows into the tables at install time.  That's a very advanced concept (similar to dynamic code generation).